# Carousel View not refresh the content

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I want to create a multi-step like this UI:

[image: 1]

So I create a `CarouselView`

```
<CarouselView>
        <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
                <local:P1 Style="{DynamicResource BindingVariables}" />
            </x:Array>
        </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

Even when I am adding the binding `RelativeSource` in page and four each list but when the properties of each page change the view still the same.

Any idea where is the problem?

Comment: where is the relevant code for the page?

Comment: <CollectionView
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ReservationStepsViewModel}}, Path=SchedulesDate, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10">
                                        <Label
                                            Text="{Binding Month}"
                                            TextColor="{Binding Color}" />****

Comment: Could you provide the viewmodel for us to test?

Comment: I fix it by reloading the item source of the carousel view thank you